# Ghost NaN values in Pandas DataFrame, strange behaviour with Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

This is a very strange problem, I tried a lot of things but I can't find a way to solve it.

I have a DataFrame with data collected from API : no problem with that, then I'm using a library which is pandas-ta (https://github.com/twopirllc/pandas-ta), so this add new columns to the DataFrame.

Of course, sometimes there is NaN values in the new columns added (there is a lot of reasons but the main one is that some indicators are length-based).

Basic problem, so basic solution, just need to type df.fillna(0, inplace=True) and it works !

But when when I check the df.values (or the conversion to_numpy()) there is still nan values.

Properties of the problem :

_NaN not found with np.where() in the array both with np.nan & pandas-ta.npNaN

_df.isna().any().any() returns False

_NaN are float values, not string

_array has a dtype equal to object

_I tried various methods to replace the NaNs, not only fillna, but with the fact that they are not recognized it does not work at all

_I also thought it was because of large numbers, but using to_numpy(dtype='float64') gives the same problem

So these values are here only when converted to numpy array and not recognized.

These values are also here when I use PCA to my dataset, where I get a message error because of the NaNs.

Thanks a lot for your time, sorry for the mistakes I'm not a native speaker.

Have a good day y'all.

Edit :

There is a screen of the operations I'm doing and the result printed, you can see one NaN value.
[image: Picture]

Comment: have you checked dtypes of each column?
strings(objects) with "NA" or "NaN" are strings, not missing values and you need to replace them with `""`

Comment: So I just checked before the convert_dtypes() method, the df has only int, float or 'O' dtype, also what I did not mentioned is that what I call NaN are printed nan without upper case

Comment: if by saying ` 'O' dtype` you mean, objects(text/string), fillna() will not work as I mentioned in my comment above

Comment: Even if I use convert_dtypes() and then I don't have anymore 'O' dtype ? The fillna method is performed after conversion, so without 'O' dtypes

Comment: I would suggest to share your part of the code which causes the problem and an example of dataframe your have...
maybe simple `inplace=True` is missing or similar, we cannot see it from your question

Comment: I edited my post, hope it's more clear now, let me know